# Orbit Simulator in Java returning odd values for velocity etc. despite correct math

Tags: java, libgdx, degrees, radians

I am using LibGDX to make an orbit simulator (elliptical as planets possess their own initial velocity) and I have the physics mapped out like so:

```
    public void move(float deltaTime, Planet planet) {

        float deltaX = planet.getPos().x - this.pos.x;
        float deltaY = planet.getPos().y - this.pos.y;
        float alpha = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX));


        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2));
        float F = G * this.m * planet.getM() / distance*distance;
        this.force.x = F * MathUtils.cos(alpha);
        this.force.y = F * MathUtils.sin(alpha);

        this.vel.x += (this.force.x / this.m) * deltaTime;
        this.vel.y += (this.force.y / this.m) * deltaTime;

        this.pos.x += this.vel.x * deltaTime;
        this.pos.y += this.vel.y * deltaTime;
    }
```

The problem is that my planet wobbles around and doesn't orbit at all. I fear my calculations in the code might be wrong as the physics are definitely double-checked and correct.

Each celestial object is a planet and I have no 'Sun' classes of any type so far. Only one `Planet` class, which only has Getter and Setter methods, a `render()` method (which seems irrelevant) and the presented `move()` method.

I find nothing necessitates the following however I will add the parameters' values I chose for the both planets:

```
        planet1 = new Planet(30, 1, new Vector2(300, 300));
        planet2 = new Planet(70, 332000, new Vector2(400, 400));
```

I am also aware LibGDX won't have the x, y coordinates of my circle in the middle but rather the bottom left. Therefore I have modified that in the constructor:

```
        this.pos = pos;
        this.pos.x -= r;
        this.pos.y -= r;
```

Comment: I didn’t check your math, but I imagine your strategy would accumulate a lot of error over time. If this is more of animation than an interactive physics simulation, I would do the math to find the position as a function of time rather than using force to calculate discrete increments of velocity which are then applied in discrete increments to the position.

Comment: Would that not be inelegant in terms of the physics and the possible application on other planets if they are to be added? And how would this strategy accumulate error? Is it just java (I'd assume not as I tried running the same code in python which resulted in the same problems)? I am aiming to make more of a simulation with accurate values (an N-Body simulation) and not an animation after all.

Comment: That's why I said "if it's more of an animation". It wouldn't be suitable for a physics simulation. I've never tried to do an orbit. I would think it would be challenging to keep an object in orbit in a discrete time-step simulation, because if it's position or velocity stray too far, it might fling out of orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been messing around and debugging the code and realised it was a very minor mistake, a classic mistake to assume that the math library's `cos()` and `sin()` functions use degrees. They don't. They use radians and that was the whole problem all along.

Instead of:

```
        this.force.x = F * MathUtils.cos(alpha);
        this.force.y = F * MathUtils.sin(alpha);
```

One must do:

```
        this.force.x = F * MathUtils.cosDeg(alpha);
        this.force.y = F * MathUtils.sinDeg(alpha);
```

I will make sure to edit the question to emphasize this problem and solution for future viewers of it.

Comment: Oh, right, radians are the default units in almost all software (Excel) and programming languages.